# echo newline character not working in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script

I have bash script which has lots of `echo` statements and also I aliased `echo` to `echo -e` both in `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`, so that new lines are printed properly for a statement like `echo 'Hello\nWorld'` the output should be

```
Hello
World
```

but the output I am getting is

```
Hello\nWorld
```

I even tried using `shopt -s expand_aliases` in the script, it doesn't help

I am running my script as `bash /scripts/scriptnm.sh`; if I run it as `. /scripts/scriptnm.sh` I am getting the desired output...

Comment: aliasing `echo` like you want is a bad practice IMHO

Comment: Use double quotes to that the \n gets interpreted. Single quotes prevent the interpretation of the \n and a bunch of other things.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The mixed history of `echo` means its default operation varies from shell to shell. POSIX [specifies](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html) that the result of `echo` is “implementation-defined” if the first argument is `-n` or any argument contains a backslash.

It is more reliable to use [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/printf.html) (either as a built-in command or an external command) where the behavior is more well defined: the C-style backslash escapes and format specifiers are supported in the format string (the first argument).

```
printf 'foo\nbar\n'
printf '%s\n%s\n' foo bar
```

---

You can control the expansion of backslash escape sequences of *bash*’s `echo` built-in command with the `xpg_echo` shell option.

Set it at the top of any ***bash*** script to make `echo` automatically expand backslash escapes without having to add `-e` to every echo command.

```
shopt -s xpg_echo
echo 'foo\nbar'
```

Comment: shopt -s xpg_echo; Worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

The recommended practice is to use `printf` for all new scripts.

```
printf '%s\n%s\n' "Hello" "World"

printf '%s\n' "Hello\nWorld"
```

Comment: +1 printf is a little more complicated to use than echo, but it more than pays off in avoiding echo's inconsistencies.

Answer (score 6):

When you use `bash myfile.sh`, Bash is ran in "batch" mode, on a *separate* process, and *does not* read its profile or rcfile.

When you use `. myfile.sh`, the file is *sourced* by the current shell process (as if its contents were typed by you), therefore it sees your currently defined aliases.

In general, it is a Very Bad Idea to write scripts that depend on any particular shell configuration, *especially* aliases, unless you define them *in the script* itself. (*Never* rely on user's `.bashrc`, even if it's your own.)

Answer (score 4):

This works fine in terminal

```
#!/bin/bash
alias echo="echo -e"
echo "Hello\nWorld"
```

save to a file and make it exeutable (chmod +x) it

run as ./your_file

Comment: run it as bash your_file and check the output.

Comment: Works as expected

Comment: but echo "Hello\nWorld" is not showing the expected output. As echo is already aliased to echo -e it should but that is not working and thats my question

Comment: Since it's bad practice to alias echo (programs that depend on it may break) you should remove the alias and in your script search for echo end replace it by echo -e

Comment: Thanks a lot LaLex for your answers, is there a way that I can achieve the expected result with the alias though it is not a good practice

Comment: Also if you don't want to search and replace each instance of echo in your script put alias echo="echo -e" at the top of your script and run it as  ". your_file" instead of "./your_file"